# How qr code triggering events works

Tags: qr-code

I wonder how qr code trigger events. There are several type of qr code (URL, vCard, download...): what trigger the correct action? There is a special code in qr code or the App reader guess the correct action to take?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so called *payload* of a QR code can consist of binary data, text or other (rarely) used type of data.

If the QR code contains text only, the reader has then to **guess** what it could be, mainly by looking at the start of the text, e.g.:

- `http://` or `http://`: a URL (web page to open)
- `BEGIN:VCARD`: a vCard contact
- `WIFI:` Wifi credentials

If the QR code contains binary data, then it's application specific data and a generic QR code reader cannot do anything with it.